# how to use Graph Theory for scheduling execution order?

Tags: java, graph-theory, job-scheduling, jgrapht, graph-traversal

I am designing an application, which executes a series of plugins. A plugin's execution might/might not be dependent on another/other plugins execution. i.e some (not all) of the plugins expect other plugin(s) to be executed before it begins its execution.

I need to derive the correct order of execution such that no plugin gets executed before the plugin it's depending on.

I believe graph theory can be used to solve this (plugins as vertex, dependency as edge, and derive execution order using some sort of traversal).

I am planning to use JGraphT since the application is being developed in Java.

Any help or pointers to solve the case ??? i am not expecting whole java code, any pointers about graph theory (algorithms to use) will be equally helpfull ....

Thanks !!!

[solution:] @Artium lead to the solution, this [link](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/DependencyDemo) shows a very similar implementation.

Comment: Refer the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40493326/1709793)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

And after a quick check, it is [easy](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/traverse/TopologicalOrderIterator.html) to do with JGraphT. 
Also notice:

> For this iterator to work correctly the graph must be acyclic, and must not be modified during iteration. Currently there are no means to ensure that, nor to fail-fast; the results with cyclic input (including self-loops) or concurrent modifications are undefined. To precheck a graph for cycles, consider using CycleDetector or StrongConnectivityInspector.

Comment: If you have a cycle, you have a plugin A that depends on a plugin B that depends A.  Topological sort not working would be the least of your problems.

Comment: @toto yes, but as @artium mentioned CycleDetector would take care of that, am in the process of trying out his suggestion, will post my progress soon

Comment: Thanks @Artium `TopologicalOrderIterator` along with a `CycleDetector` did what is required.

Comment: I am trying to use JGraphT's TopologicalOrderIterator to get a scheduling order. The iterator returns one node at a time. But in a topo sort, there might be more candidates in each iterations. Is it possible to get all the candidates so that I can do a parallel execution on them?

Comment: @amrk7 Don't familiat enpugh with JGraph, but you can mae minor alternation of Kahn's algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple load-on-demand approach, load all plugins a plugin depends on if not already loaded.

A few observations:

1. If the dependency tree is very deep (> 1,000 plugins), this could result in a StackOverflowException
2. This solution is thread-safe assuming all plugins are loaded one by one and synchronously
3. Finding illegal cycles in the "graph" is handled by using a `starting` flag that is set to `true` before loading all dependencies and set back to `false` only after the plugin is initialized
4. This case handles the situation when a plugin explicitly starts another plugin (not as part of its dependencies -- but it does not account for asynchronous initialization)

Here is an untested sample to give an idea:

```
class Plugin {
    Set<Plugin> dependencies;
    boolean started, starting;

    Plugin(Set<Plugin> deps) { dependencies = deps; }

    void start() {
        if (started) { /* already initialized */ }
        else if (starting) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cyclic plugin dependency"); }
        else {
            starting = true;
            for (Plugin p : dependencies) { p.start(); }
            /* initialize this plugin here */
            starting = false;
            started = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the plugins are not runtime dependent on each other, the application is more like a build tool, where i execute the plugins in particular sequence, in any case i wouldnt want the plugins to be hold references (set<plugin> deps), i am looking for a solution where u simply mention a particular plugins id as dependency, thus the main program based on the information would decide the execution order. Thanks.

Comment: You can still use this approach by using `int` instead of `Plugin` and basically extracting the right order of the IDs -- but doing topological sorting is your better bet.

Comment: trying to extract the right sequence of id would force the plugin writer to decide the sequence ... it can be implemented using Comparable interface, i want the program to 'resolve' the order ... i will be tryin to use the Topological Sort ... thanks